# How should I pass a string as props to a React component?

Tags: reactjs

I have a String component, which renders a title:

```
const String = (someString) => {
  return (
    <h1>{someString}</h1>
  )
}

const App = () => {
  const someString = 'abc'
  return (
    <String someString={someString}/>
  )
}

export default App;
```

However this errors out, throwing `Objects are not valid as a React child`. I can get around this by modifying the String component like so:

```
const String = (someString) => {
  return (
    <h1>{someString.someString}</h1>
  )
}
```

I'm confused why `someString` evaluates as an object in React. I can confirm it's an object by console.logging `someString` in the first String component, where I see:

`{someString: 'hello world'}`

Is this the correct way I should pass a primitive string as props, via `string.string`? From reading through some articles, I thought I should be able to simply pass `string`.

https://www.g2i.co/blog/understanding-the-objects-are-not-valid-as-a-react-child-error-in-react

Comment: the `someString` argument of the `String` function represents *all* the properties defined in the HTML-like format. Thus, that's and object, not a single string value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you need to add curly brackets in your `String` component declaration like this.

Try this:

```
const String = ({someString}) => { //this line needs curly brackets
   return (
      <h1>{someString}</h1>
   )
 }

const App = () => {
const someString = 'abc'
   return (
      <String someString={someString}/>
   )
 }

export default App;
```

Without those brackets your are referencing the whole `prop` object

Answer (score 3):

To add to the other answers, when you do `<MyComponent arg={value}/>`, this will call a function named `MyComponent` with a single argument that is an object. That object will contain a field named `arg`. We can write that function like this:

```
const MyComponent = (props) => {
  // do something with `props.arg`
}
```

However, `props` is just a convention. The parameter can be named whatever you want it to be:

```
const MyComponent = (foo) => {
  // do something with `foo.arg`
}
```

For convenience, we can use destructuring syntax to get `arg` directly:

```
const MyComponent = ({arg}) => {
  // do something with `arg`
}
```

Now we only have a variable named `arg` that contains the value we passed in.

Comment: to me, that's the way best explained answer.

Answer (score 2):

What you should be doing is:

```
const String = ({someString}) => {
  return (
    <h1>{someString}</h1>
  )
}
```

Then your original implementation should work.

This assigns `props.someString`, where as what you are doing just names `props` as `someString`.

When you use

```
const App = () => {
  const someString = 'abc'
  return (
    <String someString={someString}/>
  )
}
```

the `props` object passed to your `<String />` component is

```
{
  someString: 'abc'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**ParentComponent.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import ChildComponent from './ChildComponent';

function ParentComponent() {
  const myString = 'Hello, world!';
  return (
    <ChildComponent myProp={myString} />
  );
}

export default ParentComponent;
```

**ChildComponent.js**

```
import React from 'react';

function ChildComponent(props) {
  return (
    <div>{props.myProp}</div>
  );
}

export default ChildComponent;
```

Answer (score 0):

Moving my comments into an answer since I prefer to use the right terminology for better understanding:

React under the hood passes an object as an argument to the child component, consisting of the "props", in the child component (*function*) you can call this (*received*) parameter anything, but a naming convention is to call it `props`.

To make you visualize how that would work in vanilla JavaScript (because after all, *React components are JavaScript functions*),
here's an example without destructuring:

```js
const Parent = () => {

// calls Children function
  Children({
    someString: 'abc'
  });
}
const Children = (someString) => {
  console.log('someString as object:', someString)
}
Parent();
```

In the above example you would need to use property accessors such as the [dot notation or the bracket notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_accessors) to access the value `'abc'` from the `someString` property of the same-named `someString` Object parameter.

Below is instead an example of how that would look much simplier when you use inline [destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment):

```js
const Parent = () => {
  Children({
    someString: 'abc'
  });
}
const Children = ({ someString }) => {
  console.log('someString destructured:', someString)
}
Parent();
```

Back to your example: because React doesn't know how to render Objects (and throws errors when you try to do it) you can see why you must use either dot notations or inline destructuring if you prefer simplicity:

```
const String = ({ someString }) => {
  return (
    <h1>{someString}</h1>
  )
}

// ... the rest of your code
```

And that would read the value `'abc'` into the JSX, instead of trying to render the whole Object.